# How to stack 2 columns of data with spaces into a single column with no spaces

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 columns of data that are 40 rows each (AD2:AE42). Some of the rows will be blank based on user input. How do I stack the 2 columns with into a single column with no spaces starting at AC2?

This has to be done each time a check box on another sheet is checked or unchecked. The user will never see this sheet.

Formula or VBA solutions are both welcome.

```
Row        AC       AD      AE    <----Columns
1      FinalList   List1   List2  <----Headers
2      Bob         Bob     Steve
3      Jim         Jim     Larry
4      Mary        Mary
5      Steve
6      Larry
8-40
```

Comment: You can record a macro to do that. Probably want to use the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants,...)` property before doing the copy/paste (to get rid of the blanks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple VBA, loop through the cells, check if it's blank, and move the value.

```
For Each c In Range("AD2:AE42")
    If Not c.Value = "" Then Range("AC" & Cells(Rows.Count, 29).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = c.Value
Next c
```

This will go from left to right.

For looping through each column, you could do something like:

```
For i = 30 To 31
    For Each c In Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(42, i))
        If Not c.Value = "" Then Range("AC" & Cells(Rows.Count, 29).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = c.Value
    Next c
Next i
```

**edit**
For use on another Worksheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
For Each c In ws.Range("AD2:AE42")
    If Not c.Value = "" Then ws.Range("AC" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 29).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = c.Value
Next c
```

or

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, c As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
For i = 30 To 31
    For Each c In Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(42, i))
        If Not c.Value = "" Then ws.Range("AC" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 29).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = c.Value
    Next c
Next i
```

Comment: It only added the last entry of column AD to column AC. No errors. To be clear, I am calling this macro from another sheet, so I added Worksheets("Data"). in front of your Ranges.

Comment: Sounds like `Cells(Rows.Count, 29).End(xlUp)` is still in the wrong sheet. So it doesn't update the last used row. Henche it's writing all the values in the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an array formula that will list the values from a 2D range into a single column while removing blank values. (Ctrl-Shift-Enter) and copy down...

> The formula uses a named range 'Data' for ease of readability which would equate to `AD2:AE42`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data, 1+MOD(SMALL(IF(Data="", "", (ROW(Data)-MIN(ROW(Data))+1)+ROWS(Data)*(COLUMN(Data)-MIN(COLUMN(Data))+1)), ROW(A1))-1,ROWS(Data)),INT((SMALL(IF(Data="", "", (ROW(Data)-MIN(ROW(Data))+1)+ROWS(Data)*(COLUMN(Data)-MIN(COLUMN(Data))+1)), ROW(A1))-1)/ROWS(Data))),"")
```

**Excel 365 Update**

With support for arrays added, the following spill formulae can be used:

> again `Data` is a named range but can be replaced with AD2:AE42 in the formula if wished

```
=LET(array,Data,list,INDEX(array,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)*COLUMNS(array))/COLUMNS(array),0),MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)*COLUMNS(array),,0),COLUMNS(array))+1),FILTER(list,LEN(list)>0))
```

And adding in unique value filtering this becomes:

```
=LET(array,Data,list,INDEX(array,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)*COLUMNS(array))/COLUMNS(array),0),MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)*COLUMNS(array),,0),COLUMNS(array))+1),UNIQUE(FILTER(list,LEN(list)>0)))
```